# What is the music in the back of a song called?

Tags: phrase-requests

I can’t think of a word that describes what the instruments behind the lyrics are

Comment: Generally the notes are called "music" and the words are "lyrics".  The music of instruments (and sometimes backup singers) is "accompaniment".

Comment: Hi Bella, welcome to English Language & Usage! To better answer your question, it would help to give some example of how you're wanting to use the word, or what you've done to try to figure out the answer. See here for more information on writing great questions: https://english.stackexchange.com/tour